# Error while login into ArgoCD CLI all SubConns are in TransientFailure

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, argocd

I get below error while logging in into the `ArgoCD` cli.

```
git:(main) ✗ argocd login test.argocd.tenes.nl --sso        
WARNING: server is not configured with TLS. Proceed (y/n)? y
FATA[0005] rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: <nil>
```

I installed argocd (2.3.3 via the install guide) and added an ingress listed below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-http
    nginx.org/ssl-services: argocd-server
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.argocd.<domain>.nl
      secretName: test.argocd.<domain>.nl-tls
  rules:
    - host: test.argocd.<domain>.nl
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: argocd-server
                port: 
                  name: https
```

The weird thing is that it keeps saying that it is **non-tls** however there should be SSL forwarding? Im using the nginx.org/nginx-ingress from F5

Best,
Pim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP2 was not enabled on the ingress which is required in this case but not documented